# Vue.js delay v-if toggle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to delay a `v-if` toggle so that my element is not removed straight away but after 300 ms. I need to element to be removed from the DOM so I need to use a `v-if`.

Currently I have a somewhat hacky solution to get this done. I wrapped my `v-if` statement in a transition and set a transition with `.3s`.

I am using the opacity here but I am not doing anything with it since I do not want to fade the element out but simply delay the `v-if` toggle.

**My element:**

```
<transition name="delay-display-none">
    <div class="i-need-to-be-removed-after-300-ms"></div>
</transition>
```

**My style:**

```
.delay-display-none-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .3s
}
.delay-display-none-leave-to {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Is there a better option to get this done instead of this hacky solution?

Comment: You can do it by 2 ways: (1) use `transition-delay: 300ms` with `transition-duration: 0`, or (2) update the variable passed into v-if `300ms` after something has triggered it, using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks the first option seems like an improvement on my original solution. I guess I will stick to that. Feel free to create an answer for your solution.

Comment: Sure, I have done that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to force a delayed `v-if` response and you are already using `<transition>`, you can kind of trick a delay by using a `transition-delay` of the duration you want to wait, e.g. `transition-delay: 300ms`, and setting `transition-duration: 0` so that you do not actually fade anything.

An alternative way is to actually delay the update of the variable being passed into `v-if`. Since the variable is dynamically updated (otherwise you cannot toggle v-if), you can use `window.setTimeout(...)` to update its value instead, so that you can create a delayed effect. This solution requires slightly more care, because you would want to cancel the same timeout whenever a user quickly toggles the element, for example.